# Function operator= declared implicitly cannot be referenced - it is a deleted function

Tags: c++

```
    std::vector<Object> vec(n); 
    for (auto & member :vec)
    {
        member = anExistingObject;
    }
```

This code throws the error in the title. However, if I say

```
auto member = anExistingObject;
```

then it works fine. I just want to make a copy of `anExistingObject` for each vector element. Why does the first way throw the error?

Comment: Because your code uses copy assignment operator, and `auto member = anExistingObject` uses a copy constructor. We can't tell you more without seeing how `Object` is defined.

Comment: `std::fill(vec.begin(), vec.end(), anExistingObject);` - if that doesn't work (and it probably won't), it's because your `Object` class has, for whatever reason, implicitly deleted `operator =`, probably because something within is not copy-assignable. We need to see `Object`, and specifically, all members therein.

Comment: This is because your second line is constructing an Object, not assigning it.

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In particular it is required to see copy assignment and copy constructor of `Object` to answer the question

Comment: btw, for the specific code shown, you could also `vec.reserve(n)` rather than pre-populate with default constructions, then , `std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(vec), n, anExistingObject);` - this should avoid using copy-assignment.

Comment: What are soem reasons for why something is not copy-assignable but it is copy-constructable? I mean, I need some clues so I can go looking at the class and find the cause.

Comment: @bipll I see what you mean, misunderstood.

Comment: @SAK That's why we asked for the definition of `Object` (and its bases) : to point out the specific reason(s) that object has the copy-assignment operator seemingly implicitly deleted.

Comment: @SAK "What are soem reasons for why something is not copy-assignable" - one example; if the class defines a move-assignment operator then the implicitly defined copy-assignment operator will be `= delete`. There are other ways it can happen as well. Just one example.

Comment: @SAK This is because when you iterate over the  vector you are iterating as an reference. I mean auto& a=b ; can be done only once, coz references can be initialized only once. They cannnot be reinitialized. In other words in C++ references cannot be reseated. I.e you cannot at later point write a=c;

Comment: (Wizard hat on) you have a reference member or a const member in your class. (Wizard hat off)

Comment: Heads up. Sometimes this error can be thrown in Visual Studio if you haven't added all of the source files to your project

Answer (score 3):

> Why does the first way throw the error?

The error message explains:

> Function operator= declared implicitly cannot be referenced - **it is a deleted function**

So, you cannot copy assign, because the copy assignment operator is deleted.

> However, if I say
>
> ```
> auto member = anExistingObject;
> ```
>
> then it works fine.

So, your class is copyable-constructible. This is not assignment of an existing object.

---

> What are soem reasons for why something is not copy-assignable?

Typical cases:

- Class has reference or const members.
- Class has base class or member of class which is non-copy-assignable.
- Class has explicitly defined move constructor or move assignment operator
- The assignment operator is explicitly deleted (does not apply to this case, since the error message says that the operator is implicitly declared).

For less typical cases, refer to the specification.

You can make `Object` copy-assignable by explicitly defining a copy assignment operator for the class.

---

P.S. You could more simply construct the vector like this:

```
std::vector<Object> vec(n, anExistingObject);
```

This copy-**constructs** the elements of the vector, and does not require assignment.

Comment: I like to add for the case "Class has base class or member of class which is non-copy-assignable", it could be any array members in the class.